# How to add the child webforms page (content page) side by side to master page which consists of a static side menu in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, bootstrap-5

So I am making an ASP.NET Projects with Webforms and in that master page consists of header and a sidebar menu. the sidebar menu is static (doesn't slide) and I have 3 content pages with associated to the same master pages. Now when I add the content pages to the master page
rather than getting aligned side by side , the sidemenu is displayed over the content page.

I also tried using Flexbox and grid through bootstrap but it doesnt help

this is the master page code

```
<form id="form1" class="px-0 py-0 mx-0 my-0" runat="server">
    <div>
        <header class="px-0 py-0 mx-0 my-0" style="background-color:white;">
            <div class="px-3 py-1 " style="background-color:white">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div id="logoheader" class="d-flex flex-row">
                        
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imglogo" CssClass="mx-3 my-2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imgs/dbp-logo.png" Height="55px" Width="120px" />
                        <%--<div align="center" id="searchbar" class="form-inline col-5 d-flex align-items-center px-1" role="search">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnimgsearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imgs/search.png" Height="25px" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="searchtxt" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>--%>
                        <div class="px-1">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnNotification" class="px-1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imgs/bell.png" Height="27px" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUser" runat="server" Height="31px" ImageUrl="~/imgs/user.png" BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="px-0 py-0 border-bottom mb-3">
                <div id="menuheader" class="container-fluid d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">

                    <ul class="nav justify-content-center my-md-0 text-small">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-bluwe">Dashboard
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="dropdown show">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnMasters" runat="server" class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Masters </asp:LinkButton>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="lbtnMasters">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-blue">Tools
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <%--<main>
            <div class="flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-white" style="width: 280px;">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-3 link-dark text-decoration-none border-bottom">
                    <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="30" height="24">
                        <use xlink:href="#bootstrap" />
                    </svg>
                    <span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Collapsible</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
                    <li class="mb-1">
                        <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#home-collapse" aria-expanded="true">
                            Home
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse show" id="home-collapse">
                            <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Overview</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Updates</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Reports</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mb-1">
                        <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dashboard-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dashboard
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse" id="dashboard-collapse">
                            <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Overview</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Weekly</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Monthly</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Annually</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mb-1">
                        <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#orders-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            Orders
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse" id="orders-collapse">
                            <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">New</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Processed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Shipped</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Returned</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
                    <li class="mb-1">
                        <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#account-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            Account
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse" id="account-collapse">
                            <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">New...</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Sign out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </main>--%>
    </div>
</form>
```

Please tell how the display the content side by side